# W3C JavaScript for loop style

Tags: javascript

I was looking through the [W3C Javascript Best Practices](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Stick_to_a_strict_coding_style) and I noticed that they write their for-loops in a different way.

```
var f = document.getElementById('mainform');
var inputs = f.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0,j=inputs.length;i<j;i++){
  if(inputs[i].className === 'mandatory' &&
     inputs[i].value === ''){
    inputs[i].className += ' error';
  }
}
```

They assign the inputs length value to j and then compare j with i. Instead of just directly comparing inputs.length with i. They don't do that everywhere in the guide just in some places. Is there a reason other than a preference for writing a for-loop this way?

Comment: caching length increases loop performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/10167931#10167931), it's a performance thing.  Referencing `inputs.length` would be a runtime attribute lookup in a hash table at the top of every loop iteration.  Caching it in a local variable avoids that, and the results can be dramatic, especially on an interpreter that doesn't have JIT compilation.

Comment: I believe, this case is even worse: browser will query DOM for each iteration  because the collection could have been changed since previous step.

Answer (score 5):

**Slight performance improvement.**

Instead of reading `length` property from array again after each iteration, use cached version.

This will be very very small amount of time that this can be ignored for moderate sized arrays.